# Java library for map plotting?

Tags: java, dictionary, gps, plot

I have some large datasets of timestamped GPS coordinated which I want to plot on a map.

Because I want to plot a large amount of points and also read the data from files first, web APIs like Leaflet and Google Maps are not suitable (I have tried).

I also need to map to be detailed to the level of streets been visible.

Can anyone suggest a Java library for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use minigeo, OpenStreetMap

**Minigeo** is a lightweight Java library that allows one to plot geographical data (namely lines between points determined by geographic coordinates.

https://code.google.com/p/minigeo/

Comment: This would be good, but it is a bit too simple. It only allows plotting of lines between points, and no plotting of individual points.

Comment: Not that simple. However, it is open source so I have managed to implement the plotting of a single point myself. Works just as I want :)

Comment: Well done @JamesWalker +1 for the question because of the effort you applied :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapforge as it is offline utility for both Android and desktop.

https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge